# Не отправляет данные в БД php

Tags: php, база-данных

```html
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "zlatan", "123456", "ayan");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $login = $POST['login'];
    $password = $POST['password'];
    $rpassword = $POST['r-password'];
    $email = $POST['email'];


}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Главная страница</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Главная страница</h2>
    <form action="ayan.php" method="post">
    <br>

    <input type="text" name="login" required placeholder="|Login">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="|Password">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="r-password" required placeholder="|R-Password">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="|E-mail">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Регистрация">
    <br>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $POST забыли нижнее подчеркивание? а где собственно отправка в бд?)

Answer (score 1):

забыли нижнее подчеркивание в переменных $_POST

правильный вариант:

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rpassword = $_POST['r-password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $login = $POST['login'];
    $password = $POST['password'];
    $rpassword = $POST['r-password'];
    $email = $POST['email'];


}
```

Такой вариант должен работать.